# Conversion of summation to integral

Tags: riemann-sum

Consider an integer with $N$ digits (in decimal notation, without leading zeroes) $D_1, D_2, D_3, \ldots , D_N$. Here, $D_1$ is the most significant digit and $D_N$ the least significant. The weight of this integer is defined as

$$\sum_{i=2}^N (D_i - D_{i-1})$$

Could you help me convert the summation to integral?
I need to find the weight of the number here.
Thanks
Edit N tends to infinity

Comment: I've edited the question...could u have a look again? Thnx

Comment: The sum telescopes. It's just $D_N-D_1$